# Is there a way to run JMH without forking a new java process?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microbenchmark, jmh

I'm working on a spring project. It has to perform several DB operations (in several methods) while running. I want to measure the exact execution time of some methods in my project(while running). 
Some of Those methods also have to perform DB operations.
Now, when I use @Benchmark on those methods and run my project, my project run well. But JMH forks a new java process and get NullPointerException at those points that related to performing DB operations. 
 
I know, by default JHM forks a new java process for each trial (set of iterations). But I need to run JMH within the same process (of my running project). 
How can I run JMH without forking a new java project? 
In short, I'm trying to measure the exact execution time of some methods (that involves DB operations) while my project is running.

Comment: @Eugene: it is forking by default, it's in the same class you added link to: "JMH will fork the tests by default."

Comment: Without forking, your benchmark will be skewed. Forking ensures that the JVM did not yet build a profile that optimizes your code for a specific context. Without forking, the first benchmark influences the outcome of your second and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **set fork to 0**

There are many ways to do so:

Annotation to class:

```
@Fork(0)
public class YourTestClass { //...
```

Or annotation to specific benchmark (if applies to only one benchmark)

```
@Benchmark
@Fork(0)
public void yourTest()
```

Or by setting Options in main (applies to entire run):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .forks(0)
            // other arguments come here
            .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();
}
```

Or by command-line arguments (also applies to entire run):

```
java -jar yourbenchmark.jar -f 0
```

Note that creators of JMH do not recommend disabling forking, if precision of the benchmark is important:

> So, do not set forks to zero until you know what you are doing.

([source](http://java-performance.info/jmh/))

Comment: I've tried with fork=0 (in all possible ways you told), but it still gets NullPointerException.

Comment: I think I should add something about the method I'm trying to benchmark. This method works on a @_Inject and @_Autowired field and updates DB. And that @_Autowired field has been run through several processing in several methods before this method is being executed.